How can I plot the Internet usage (MB/s) as a function of time on iOS?
I can plot the Internet usage (MB/s) as a function of time on Windows with WhatPulse:

or on Android with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network:

How can I plot the Internet usage (MB/s) as a function of time on iOS?

You'll have to search the App Store for an app that does this.

@benwiggy oh wow thanks! Do you leave that insightful comment on all software recommendation questions?

Normally I go with "software recommendations are off-topic", or "please show what research you've done." or "What problem are you trying to solve.?"

@benwiggy "software recommendations are off-topic" is incorrect, "please show what research you've done." is not required "What problem are you trying to solve.?" is not your business.
